# ¿Por qué al guardar un asterisco en una variable y luego imprimirla se sustituye por todos los elementos de la ruta actual?

Tags: bash

Tengo problemas guardando un asterisco en una variable dentro de un script Bash. Las entradas que uso son -1 y 1.

```
#!/bin/bash

function aleatorio {
    printf "((%d %% 1000) / 1000,0) * (%f - %f) + %f\n" $RANDOM $2 $1 $1
}

X=`aleatorio -1 1`
echo $X
```

Cuando imprimo la variable `$X`, ese asterisco se sustituye por todos los elementos de la ruta actual. He probado también con comillas simples.

La salida que obtengo al ejecutar el programa es:

> ((12210 % 1000) / 1000,0) CarloMagno.sh Descargas Documentos git.txt Imágenes Practica_03_AC Practica_03_IA Practica_04_FIS Programacion ProgramasPortables Prueba.sh scriptVectorNUltraDimensional.sh TareasPendientes.txt Universidad (1,000000 - -1,000000) + -1,000000

Esos son los elementos que hay en la carpeta donde ejecuto el Script. Eso pasa tanto usando comillas dobles, como comillas simples, como \*

Comment: Hola Class, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Puedes dar ejemplos de texto y la salida esperada? Asi como el resultado actual que te produce el codigo  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info.  Un saludo.

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu error. Si hago `r=1; s=1; t=1; v=1; printf "((%d %% 1000) / 1000,0) * (%f - %f) + %f\n" $r $s $t $v` me los escribe perfectamente. ¿Qué comando estás ejecutando _exactamente_?

Comment: @OscarGarcia sí, efectivamente. Pero esto seguramente es indicador de que está haciendo algo raro (redirigiendo luego a `bc` probablemente), de ahí que sea bueno tener un ejemplo de lo que no funciona.

Comment: @OscarGarcia bueno, de hecho dándole una vuelta más lo más sencillo es utilizar `$(( expresión ))` para que la expansión aritmética haga el trabajo. Lo puse ahora en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash no es el mejor lenguaje para tratar con expresiones aritméticas que requieren de punto flotante. Si quiers utilizar algo limpio y rápido, ¡usa Awk!

```
$ awk -v r="$RANDOM" -v v1=-1 -v v2=1 'BEGIN {print (r % 1000)/1000 * (v2-v1) + v1}'
0.948
```

En el contexto de un script podrías hacer:

```
function aleatorio {
    awk -v r="$RANDOM" -v v1=$1 -v v2=$2 'BEGIN {print (r % 1000)/1000 * (v2-v1) + v1}'
}

res_aleatorio=$(aleatorio -1 1)
echo "$res_aleatorio"
```

Como ves, pasamos las variables a Awk utilizando `-v variable="$variable_en_bash"`.

---

Si tuvieras una expresión aritmética sin punto flotante, podrías  ejecutarla con `$(( expresión ))`:

```
$ echo "$(( 2 * 4 ))"
8
$ v=4; echo "$(( 2 * $v ))"
8
```

Esto se explica en [Bash Reference Manual → 3.5.5 Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

---

**¿Pero por qué `*` se está expandiendo a la lista de ficheros en tu ruta?**

En Bash, `*` tiene un valor especial que hace que en según qué contextos se expanda al listado de ficheros y posibles directorios y subdirectorios desde el punto en el que estás.

Lo mismo pasa con `?`, que coincide con un carácter.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/prueba
$ cd /tmp/prueba

# Creamos dos ficheros: a y aa
$ touch a aa

$ echo *
a aa         # Se expande a todo
$ echo ?
a            # Se expande a todo lo que tenga 1 carácter
$ echo ??
aa           # Se expande a todo lo que tenga 2 caracteres
```

Por tanto, si quieres imprimir un asterisco, debes o bien entrecomillarlo, o bien escaparlo:

```
$ echo '*'
*
$ echo \*
*
```

Tienes más información en [Bash Reference Manual → 3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), donde puedes ver que por ejemplo puedes deshabilitar la opción:

```
$ set -f
$ echo *
*
```

Comment: No puedo usar `$(( ... ))` porque es una operación en coma flotante

Comment: Al usar `set -f` si que funciona

Comment: @class_OpenGL es un buen truco :) Alternativamente, puedes usar Awk, que tiene mejor uso (y más claro) de los números flotantes.

Answer (score 3):

Tras la edición de la pregunta me he fijado que ese cálculo matemático puedes resolverlo con la herramienta [`bc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) que soporta operaciones decimales (a diferencia del operador de expansión aritmética [`$(( ... ))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) que trabaja sólo con enteros).

Esta modificación a tu código lo haría funcionar correctamente:

```
#!/bin/bash

function aleatorio {
    LANG=C printf "( 0.001 * (%d %% 1000)) * (%f - %f) + %f\n" $RANDOM $2 $1 $1 | bc
}

X=$(aleatorio -1 1)
echo "$X"
```

Por un lado le paso a `bc` la expresión para que la resuelva y por otro lado le indico a `printf` que no use decimales "localizados" (con comas `,` en vez de puntos `.` en el separador decimal) para que `bc` no se queje de ello.

También se podría haber usado `echo` para evitarnos usar `LANG=C` en `printf`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function aleatorio {
    echo "( 0.001 * ($RANDOM % 1000)) * ($2 - $1) + $1" | bc
}

X=$(aleatorio -1 1)
echo "$X"
```

La solución explicada cuando tratábamos de explicarte cómo mostrar una variable que contiene un asterisco sin que éste se interprete está [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/162817/3).

Comment: no sé con qué Bash trabajas (yo con la 4.3.48), pero a mí tanto `echo "$X"` como `echo $X` me devuelven lo mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Has probado usando `\` ? Ya que es la marca de escapada de carácteres.

```
printf "((%d %% 1000) / 1000,0) \* (%f - %f) + %f\n" $RANDOM $2 $1 $1
```

Comment: Si, muy a mi pesar (siento no haberlo añadido)